# Why is "Detail" in genitive in "aufgrund einer Einigung [...] mit geheimen finanziellen Details"?

Tags: preposition, dative, genitive

Here's the full sentence:

> Am ersten April 2018 erschien als Aprilscherz ein Blog-Post auf dem
> offiziellen NewPipe-Blog, der ankündigte, dass die App bald auch im
> Playstore erhältlich sein würde, aufgrund einer Einigung mit Google
> mit geheimen finanziellen Details.

I understand that "aufgrund" leads genitive, but "mit" leads dative. But shouldn't "Detail" follow "mit", which is closer?

Source:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/NewPipe

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. *Details* is not in genitive but in dative. *Einer Einigung* is genitive.

Comment: The confusion probably comes from _Details_ being plural and therefore looking the same as the genitive singular form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right in that "mit" leads dative, but "geheimen finanziellen Details" is dative plural here, not genitive.

While the expression "geheimen finanziellen Details" itself is ambiguous (it could be genitive singular or dative plural), the genitive singular of "geheimes finanzielles Detail" would need an article.

Genitive singular, for example with "aufgrund" or "wegen" would be:

> eines geheimen finanziellen Details

or

> des geheimen finanziellen Details

Comment: All my bad. I thought Detail's plural would be Detailen. Weirdly, it isn't in my dictionary.